# How to start mac installation with arguments in unattended mode?

Tags: install4j

Now I have a question for the mac os. I activated the unattended mode for the installer and tried out this on a win system. There it works fine. Now I wanted to start the installer on a mac os but didn't get it run correctly. I tried the following command:

```
open MyApp.app --args -q -console -varfile my.varfile
```

This starts always the GUI installation instead the unattended mode. Maybe the terminal command is incorrect?

Kind regards
Hardie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"/bin/open" is not suitable for command line-style invocations, since the passing of arguments is not synchronous and they are not passed to the main method. Instead, call the executable directly:

```
MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/JavaApplicationStub -q -varfile my.varfile
```

Btw: "-console" is not applicable for Mac OS X, only for Windows.